# Pass a file's "data" instead of the actual file in Python

Tags: python, file, base64

I am using a resume parsing python library that accepts a pdf file and returns JSON. The code is as simple as below:

`parsed_data = ResumeParser("file.pdf").get_extracted_data()`

I wanted to expose an API around this, so in API the pdf data is sent as a base64 string. So, I first write the data to a file and then run the above code. My current code looks as below:

```
def parse(b64data): 
    bytes = b64decode(b64data, validate=True)
    f = open('tmp_file.pdf', 'wb')
    f.write(bytes)
    f.close()
    parsed_data = ResumeParser("tmp_file.pdf").get_extracted_data()
    return parsed_data
```

Is there any better approach for me to avoid writing the data to a file? I am exposing this API as a serverless function and I think I can save time by not doing write.

**References:**

- https://github.com/OmkarPathak/pyresparser (Library Used)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library that you are using appears to accept a `BytesIO` object as an alternative to passing it a string that contains a filename.  However, it also appears to expect that this `BytesIO` object has a `name` attribute from which it extracts an extension so it can determine the filetype.  So, we will add a bogus `name` attribute that contains the string `.pdf` to our `BytesIO` object.

So, we should be able to use something like this:

```
import io, base64

def parse(b64data): 
    bytes = base64.b64decode(b64data, validate=True)
    bytesio = io.BytesIO(bytes)
    bytesio.name = '.pdf'
    parsed_data = ResumeParser(bytesio).get_extracted_data()
    return parsed_data
```